# Is there a word for the combination of efficiency and diligence?

Tags: single-word-requests

Basically a word for someone who works hard and works smart?

Comment: Would you say that somebody is 'efficient but not diligent?' - a worker could not be efficient without working hard: they can be efficient in the short term, but lack of diligence leads to inefficiency in the overall performance. Hence in the context of work, *'diligence' would be implied within the meaning of 'efficiency'* (but not the reverse: efficiency is not necessarily implied within diligence, because somebody can be diligent yet inefficient, due to certain limitations) - so *efficient* seems a good enough term for your purpose; you may not really need a single word to describe the two.

Comment: I realized this like eleven minutes ago; thanks anyways! I spent the last six minutes looking up how to mark my question as answered. 

EDIT: I mean, it was more like I realized that diligence would be irrelevant if it were inefficient. I actually think you can be efficient without being diligent; for example, making a simple tool to take care of the work requires a lot less diligence and is much more efficient.

Comment: ( _ requires a lot less diligence _ ) In fact diligence relates not to the volume of work but the 'willingness to work hard.' So if somebody is not diligent then they are basically lazy, and I have found such persons quite inefficient in the long term, even if they dazzle with a bit of clever efficiency from time to time! In the long run such a person would be found inefficient. Note 2: you cannot mark your question as answered till somebody answers it;  you got the understanding you were looking for, but you can check here from time to time to see the other responses from our learned members!

Comment: I'm aware. Now I want to know the word for someone who works efficiently and works relevantly. E.g. you can be really efficient at playing video games, and you can be really inefficient at solving poverty.

Comment: Efficiency is not expected in unrelated work domains. It is usually applied to specific areas of work, unless you use it to describe somebody in general as 'an efficient person' which means he/she is efficient at all type of tasks. But people are usually expected to be efficient mainly at their own work. Ed is an inefficient typist but an efficient cook: no problem, *if his job is cooking!* So **just like diligence, relevance is also implied in efficiency** -  somebody who is efficient at something irrelevant, but inefficient in the relevant work area, is *simply inefficient* for our purposes!

Comment: @EnglishStudent You can be diligent but inefficient, making all (or most) of your efforts go to waste. You can be working efficiently but not diligently, not working as much as your peers do, but getting as much work done as they do. You can also be both or neither. They're not qualities that are tied together.

Comment: @John Hamilton I am mainly interested in how somebody can work 'efficiently but not diligently':  maybe you mean that an efficient person does not need to work as hard as a less efficient person to get the same work done, (which is very likely) and possibly such a person 'may not be diligent' as in, they don't try to get *more* work done in the time saved by being more efficient -- what I should like to understand is: if the person in question were efficient enough to get their work done quickly, yet did not try to convert the time saved into more work, would they be considered 'not diligent?'

Comment: @John Hamilton there is something very similar related to schoolwork -- 'intelligent but not industrious' is written by many teachers in school (and even college) reports, as in 'student A is intelligent but not industrious' (means -- he/she is a very efficient student and could achieve much better results by being more diligent!')

Comment: @EnglishStudent that is exactly how it is. Like I said, they're not tied together but they're both tied to productivity. You could actually say `productivity = diligence x efficiency` and it would be pretty close to reality.

Comment: @John Hamilton Thanks for the explanation. Now you have found a word that perfectly describes OP's ideal worker: *efficient* **and** *diligent*: he/she would be highly **productive!** So please edit your answer and give OP this excellent solution.

Answer (score 1):

"word for someone who works hard and works smart"

working:

```
determinedly
keenly
resolutely
enterprisingly
industriously
nimbly
astutely
adroitly
```

Those work for me!

Answer (score 0):

I'd say if a person is working hard and is also efficient in doing his work, then he must be **working like a well-oiled-machine** or quite possibly **working like a robot**. Although, robot could be misunderstood as emotionless and a negative quality so I'd avoid using that one.